# Android: Zoom while scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-animation, zooming

I am looking for a solution to my problem of zooming during the scrolling.

If you scroll horizontally to the object in the center appear larger. Like the mouse-over effect of the dock of mac osx.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the sample HelloGallery project I posted here

[ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 issues - test hangs because of invalidate() call in the code I'm writing a test for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168527/activityinstrumentationtestcase2-issues-test-hangs-because-of-invalidate-cal)

Its based on this CoverFlow implementation
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html